# Defining multiple Spring Converters with target type Optional?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, generics, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.10 and have a problem with my custom converters.

I'm defining multiple converters with target type Optional
Something like this:

```
@Component
public class StringToSomeTypeConverter implements Converter<String, Optional<SomeType>> { ... }


@Component
public class StringToOtherTypeConverter implements Converter<String, Optional<OtherType>> { ... }
```

My problem is that there is apparently only one converter registered for the type Optional. So at runtime only one Converter gets called in all my Controllers. No matter the generic target type. (`SomeType` or `OtherType` in the example)

I did some digging and the converter is chosen in `GenericConversionService#getConverter`.
The method takes `TypeDescriptor targetType` as argument and constructs a `ConverterCacheKey` from `sourceType` and `targetType`.
Sadly `TypeDescriptor#equals` only compares `getType()` (Optional) and not `resolvableType` (`SomeType` or `OtherType` in our example).
This explains why only one Converter gets picked up.

Is there any way to make Spring aware of the `ResolvableType` so I can use Optional as my target type for multiple Converters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can not tell for sure what is going on, but having browsed Spring MVC source code many times I guess the problem would be in some code that is iterating thorugh registered Converters and checking if they can convert, so the target type would be Optional(not Optional< Class < Integer > >, but Optional), if you run this code:

```
Optional<Class<String>> ops = Optional.of(String.class);
Optional<Class<Integer>> ops2 = Optional.of(Integer.class);
System.out.println(ops2.getClass().equals(ops.getClass()));
```

You will see on the console, it prints true, meaning, they are considered as the same datatype !! so if Spring truly iterates through the list of converters, it makes sense that hte first one is always called, because it can handle all Optional objects no matter what, my suggestion would be:

- Implement HttpMessageConverter: the reason is because it has one method called canRead and canWrite in which you can add your custom logic to check if you can really read that type or not by retrieving the Generic class used by Optional
- If you really want to use Converter, implement also ConditionalConverter, from the docs from Converter it is telling you that you may also implement ConditionalConverter, read it at https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html and https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/ConditionalConverter.html

Update: If you are interested in debugging that at Spring framework you have to place a breakpoint on methods from the ConversionService interface, it is the service that manages the conversions, at least this is how it works in Spring Core, and you will should see the execution flow and at one moment in time is checking which converter is suitable and if some of them implements ConditionalConverter, look at one of the core methods of this process yourself at: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/support/GenericConversionService.java#L560